# $(this).qtip is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog, qtip, thickbox

I've following code in my page which applies qtip on images. It displays dynamic content for each image through ajax post. But It doesn't display qtip after Thickbox/Jquery  UI dialog closes and throws error : **$(this).qtip is not a function**

```
<script src="<%= Config.VirtualDir %>js/jquery.js?v=2" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%= Config.VirtualDir %>js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js?v=2" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
     BindQtip();
});
 function BindQtip()
 {
$('image').each(function(){
                        $(this).live('click',function() {
                            var $img = $(this);
                            if('<%= objAdminAuth.GetUserID() %>' == $img.attr('data-uid').split('|')[0])
                            {                                        
                                return false;
                            }
                           if ($img.data('qtip')) {return false;} 
                            $(this).qtip({
                                content: 'Loading...',
                                style: {
                                    border: {
                                        width: 5,
                                        radius: 10
                                    },
                                    padding: 0,
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                                    name: 'dark' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
                                },
                                hide: 'unfocus',
                                show: {
                                    when: 'click', // Don't specify a show event
                                    ready: true, // Show the tooltip when ready
                                    solo: true
                                },
                                position: {
                                    corner: {
                                        tooltip: 'rightMiddle', // Use the corner...
                                        target: 'bottomLeft' // ...and opposite corner
                                    }
                                },
                                api: {
                                    // Retrieve the content when tooltip is first rendered
                                    onRender: function() {

                                        var self = this;
                                        self.content = '';
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: window.location.href,
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: 'call=ajax&uid=' + $img.attr('data-uid'),
                                            success: function(resp) {
                                                self.updateContent(resp);
                                            }
                                        });

                                    },
                                    onContentUpdate: function() {
                                        var self = this;
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        });
}
</script>
```

All path are correct and other things work perfectly. Am I missing anything?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like your registration of the js is occuring after your specific code is run. perhaps try another method (register in master) to link your js and test to see if that's it.

Comment: Are you sure the qTip library loads correctly?

Comment: Put alert() before BindQtip(). If it works that ericosg is right.

Comment: also the last line should be script not scrpit =)

Comment: Both JS reference are in master and function is in child. Could you elaborate on registering method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using AJAX to insert HTML in the current document, and this HTML is generated by the script that displays the initial page as well. This means there's a high chance that `<script>` tags such as those for jQuery and qTip are included not only in your initial page but also inside your AJAX responses. If this is true, these "later" scripts will overwrite stuff inside `window.$` with results identical to what you describe.

So, check if your AJAX includes the scripts and if it does, remove them. Everything should then work correctly.

Comment: You're the man! you rock! Issue resolved. Have you encountered similar issue earlier? Any link or reference for the same will be appreciated. Thanks a lot once again. :)

Comment: @user686021: Yeah, I had this problem myself in the past. If you look at the jQuery source you 'll see that it unconditionally overwrites `window.$` (which takes all plugins and all state with it) -- and then the pieces start clicking together.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is likely the suspect line:

```
$(this).live('click',function() {
```

Have another look at [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in the documentation, the idea is that you give it a *selector*, rather than an element, and it then matches that selector against all events of the given type that reach the document.

This odd and confusing syntax is one of the reasons `live` is deprecated in favor of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) in v1.7 or later (or my preference, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate), which was available as of v1.4.2). With both `on` and `delegate`, you specify the actual element you want to watch for events on, and then a selector to match against descendants for the delegation bit.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector `$('image')` will select all HTML elements tagged `<image>` and I don't believe there are any ...

Comment: There're HTML <image> elements on the page. Thanks.

Comment: What? And you are using HTML 6 or some strange version I don't know? There is no HTML `<image>` element afaik. There is a `<img>` or a `<input type="image">`

Comment: Actually I am using SVG. Please check [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElementHrefAttribute)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying ... you should have mentioned that in the first place :-)

Comment: Sorry for that, but I felt that It was not that much important. Any will take care next time. Thanks. :)